# Non-tailed rejection regions?

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing

From my basic understanding of statistics, the rejection region represents the area of the PDF that would be equally or more extreme than a given α-level. Typically, these regions either reside on one (or both) tails/ends of the distribution.

But what if we considered the rejection region as a fraction of the area of the total PDF? Would it be possible to shift the rejection region to any arbitrary set of points whose interval(s) represent the area of the α-level?

Consider the following scenario:

> - α=.05
> - the rejection region is centered about the median
> - the bounds of the rejection region are placed at the 47.5th and 52.5th percentile
> - the tails of the distribution are unaffected

Are there any practical examples similar to this, or is my brain just thinking of some 'fuzzy' math?

Comment: Aren't you talking about TOST procedure? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_test

Answer (score 0):

> rejection region represents the area of the PDF that would be equally or more extreme than a given α-level.

This statement leaves open the question, which PDF to use. This is crucial for the answer.  In classical NHST we define and compute *the PDF assuming the null hypothesis was true*. Your proposal basically says: If the Null of $\theta_{true} = 0$ being true holds, I consider $\theta_{observed}\approx0$ an extreme event. That certainly does not feel right.

However, if we turn away from NHST and towards Bayes statistics, things change dramatically: We no longer investigate the PDF under some null hypothesis but the assumed PDF of the parameter itself (it is then called a "posterior probability distribution"). Nothing will stop you from calculating probabilities for any arbitrary region within that "posterior"-PDF that you choose, not even a region around zero.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the reasoning about the Bayesian part: when trying to assess whether or not a parameter $\theta$ is close to $0$, say, one looks at the posterior probability of a neighbourhood of $0$ and, if large enough (depending on the decision criterion), accept the hypothesis...

Comment: @Xi'an That is how it was meant and if I was not clear enough about that I am glad if your comment clarifies it. I will add the term "posterior" to my answer.